# string to date and hour conversion

Tags: r, date, time

I have a data frame with `date and hour` string for eg. `2013-12-25_00` in the form of `YYYY-MM-DD_H`. I am trying to convert this string to Date and hour but till now I have not succeded.

My code till now:

```
test = "2013-12-25_06"
t1 = gsub("_", " ", test, fixed=TRUE)
z <- as.POSIXct(t1,format="%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

It is returning date & hour as shown below

```
"2013-12-25 06:00:00 IST"
```

I want it like `"2013-12-25 06"`

I will appriciate any help in this regard.

Comment: You need to `format` it `format(as.POSIXct(test, "%Y-%m-%d_%H"), "%Y-%m-%d %H")`  a date time class include hour minute and seconds

Comment: I have tried to format as mentioned by akrun but it is returning H 00 instead of 06.

Comment: I forgot to add the `format` i.e. `format(as.POSIXct(test, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H"), "%Y-%m-%d %H")`

Comment: Now it worked..   Thanks for the help...

Comment: It is just a character vector which would be the same as your string substitution

Comment: Ok... thanks again for the clarification